# User Assertion: 1: Update query failed -- RUNNER_DEAD

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

We are using MongoDB (v2.6.4) to process some data and everything works great except, once in a while, we get a weird RUNNER_DEAD exception...

```
MongoDB.Driver.WriteConcernException: WriteConcern detected an error ' Update query failed -- RUNNER_DEAD'. (Response was { "lastOp" : { "$timestamp" : NumberLong("6073471510486450182") }, "connectionId" : 49, "err" : " Update query failed -- RUNNER_DEAD", "code" : 1, "n" : 0, "ok" : 1.0 }).
```

This is the method that causes the exception:

```
private void UpdateEntityClassName(EntityClassName myEntity) {
    var dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var update = Update<EntityClassName>.Set(p => p.Data, myEntity.Data)
                 ...some more Sets...
                 .Set(p => p.MetaData.LastModifiedDateTime, dateTimeNow);

    var result = _myCollection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", myEntity.Identifier), update, UpdateFlags.Upsert);
}
```

Exception in MongoDB log:

```
2014-10-23T13:51:29.989-0500 [conn45] update Database.Table query: { _id: "SameID" } update: { $set: { Data: BinData(0, SomeData...), ...more fields... MetaData.LastModifiedDateTime: new Date(1414090294910) } } nmoved:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:2344 2ms
2014-10-23T13:51:29.989-0500 [conn49] User Assertion: 1: Update query failed -- RUNNER_DEAD
2014-10-23T13:51:29.989-0500 [conn46] update Database.Table query: { _id: "SameID" } update: { $set: { Data: BinData(0, SomeData...), ...more fields... MetaData.LastModifiedDateTime: new Date(1414090294926) } } nMatched:1 nModified:1 fastmod:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:249 0ms
2014-10-23T13:51:29.989-0500 [conn49] update Database.Table query: { _id: "SameID" } update: { $set: { Data: BinData(0, SomeData...), ...more fields... MetaData.LastModifiedDateTime: new Date(1414090294864) } } nModified:0 keyUpdates:0 exception:  Update query failed -- RUNNER_DEAD code:1 numYields:1 locks(micros) w:285 8ms
```

I found very little documentation about this exception so any help appreciated.

---

We are running this in a 3 machine replica set if that changes anything.

We've been running this code for a while and we didn't have that issue before (in our original tests) so we went back to MongoDB 2.4.9 (the one we first tested on) and we don't get this exception anymore. Any ideas as to what might have changed that causes this exception?

Comment: This may have been answered in our Google Groups, check it out and let me know: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/zCExRGo9jrQ

Comment: I have read that thread, but it really doesn't answer much. All it says is that this might be some kind of concurrency problem. It also says: "it might be a case a case where either something is killing the operation or dropping the collection you're writing to". The collection is definetely not getting dropped and as far as something killing the operation, well, that's what i'm looking for, the possible causes. Also, I imagined file locks would prevent that kind of concurrency problem.

Comment: We've been running this code for a while and we didn't have that issue before (in our original tests) so we went back to MongoDB 2.4.9 (the one we first tested on) and we don't get this exception anymore. Any ideas as to what might have changed that causes this exception?

Answer (score 0):

> Why you couldn't use a regular "update" using capped arrays to
>   limit the size of the array of queries rather than using some custom
>   logic).
>
> If you have multiple threads that are doing the same thing, your code
>   doesn't appear thread-safe - let's say that two threads try to update
>   the same object with _id XYZ but with different changes. Both fetch
>   the object, both add a new attribute/value to the array and now both
>   call save - the first one saves, but the second one's save overwrites
>   the first one.
>
> But that's not likely to be related to your error with `RUNNER_DEAD`
>   error - that's more likely a case where either something is killing
>   the operation or dropping the collection you're writing to (or the
>   index being used).

Source: [@Asya Kamsky's post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/zCExRGo9jrQ/_XowSPsxQGYJ).